# How to define the triplets a SPARQL query consider during its execution? (creating self-contained examples)

Tags: sparql, wdqs

## Prologue

In SQL, it is possible to define the data a `SELECT` statement consider during its execution. I call these type of examples "self-contained examples" because they create the data the query runs on. The following are two examples of such queries.

The following query creates a "temporary table" with data using `WITH`. The data is then queried with a `SELECT` statement.

```sql
WITH foo AS (
  (SELECT 1 AS c1, 10 AS c2, 100 AS c3)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT 2 AS c1, 20 AS c2, 200 AS c3)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT 3 AS c1, 30 AS c2, 300 AS c3)
)
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

```
 c1 | c2 | c3  
----+----+-----
  1 | 10 | 100
  2 | 20 | 200
  3 | 30 | 300
```

The following query creates a temporary table and then inserts the data. The data is then queried with a `SELECT` statement.

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (
  c1 INT,
  c2 INT,
  c3 INT
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES
(1, 10, 100),
(2, 20, 200),
(3, 30, 300);

SELECT * FROM foo;
```

```
 c1 | c2 | c3  
----+----+-----
  1 | 10 | 100
  2 | 20 | 200
  3 | 30 | 300
```

## The question

I want to do something similar with SPARQL. I want my query to define/create the triplets the query runs on.

I've tried using `VALUES`. I thought the following did the job.

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX : <http://example.org/book/>
PREFIX ns: <http://example.org/ns#>

SELECT ?a ?b ?c {}
VALUES (?a ?b ?c) {
  (:book1 dc:title "SPARQL Tutorial")
  (:book1 ns:price 42)
  (:book2 dc:title "The Semantic Web")
  (:book2 ns:price 23)
}
```

```
a,b,c
http://example.org/book/book1,http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title,SPARQL Tutorial
http://example.org/book/book1,http://example.org/ns#price,42
http://example.org/book/book2,http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title,The Semantic Web
http://example.org/book/book2,http://example.org/ns#price,23
```

However, when I try to filter the results, no rows are returned. [Link to the query in WDQS](https://w.wiki/4j8R).

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX : <http://example.org/book/>
PREFIX ns: <http://example.org/ns#>

SELECT ?a ?b ?c {
  ?a dc:title "The Semantic Web".
}
VALUES (?a ?b ?c) {
  (:book1 dc:title "SPARQL Tutorial")
  (:book1 ns:price 42)
  (:book2 dc:title "The Semantic Web")
  (:book2 ns:price 23)
}
```

```
a,b,c
```

My question is: What alternatives do I have for creating such type of examples (they define the triplets the query runs on) in SPARQL?

Comment: that is impossible in SPARQL - you cannot generate RDF triples, neither with VALUES nor with anything else - and triple patterns like `?a dc:title "The Semantic Web".` are only evaluated on the RDF triples of the underlying RDF dataset and not on intermediate bindings.